# how can i optimize td in react js

Tags: reactjs, optimization

i am optimizing code in react js i have almost optimized half of the code.But now i wanted to optimize td how can i achieve this..

```
let  th = ["createdAt", "name", "email", "mobile"], td = []
```

Code i have optimized for header and working fine

```
  {th.map((item, index) => {
                        return <th key={index} onClick={() => this.setState({column: item}, this.sortData)}>{item}{imgSource}</th>
                  })}
```

I am fetching data from api..I want alternate option of this code using only single td

```
  {this.state.data.people && this.state.data.people.map((item, index) => {
                         return <tr key={index}>
                             <td><h5>{item.createdAt}</h5></td>
                             <td><h5>{item.name}</h5></td>
                             <td><h5>{item.email}</h5></td>
                             <td><h5>{item.mobile}</h5></td>
                            </tr>
                    })}
```

Comment: What is the point of pushing item into td, you could just use `people` array instead. Question is not clear. Can you post codesandbox to better clarify question.

Comment: how can i achieve this..pls tell me ...Thanks

Comment: plz look above code i have updated..Thanks @tarzenchugh

Comment: I am assuming your code is working fine and just want to put `td` code dynamic and like `th`. You could iterate over `th` inside `tr` and `return <td><h5>{item[itemTd]}</h5></td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to write the generation of your `td` tags in a shorter way. This will not increase performance though. Try this:

```
{this.state.data.people && this.state.data.people.map((item, index) => {
   return <tr key={index}>
   {
     th.map((thItem, trIndex) => <td><h5>{item[thItem]}</h5></td>)
   }
   </tr>
})}
```